# HttpURLConnection POST response gets lost when server takes longer to respond

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm having trouble catching a response to a POST request to server, when the server takes a bit longer to respond (when it is passed a bigger `JSONObject`).

When we call a `GET` method with a longer response time, there is no problem. When we call a `POST` and pass a relatively small `JSONObject`, the method registers a response.
The method is being called from an `AsyncTask` via `new Task().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`.

When triggered from Postman, the response returns after 155 seconds, but it arrives. On the other hand, when triggered from the app, the code does nothing and ultimately tiggers a `SocketTimeoutException`.(For whatever reason, we have a timeout(connection and read timeout) set to 10 minutes) The code snippet for the service method is below. I'd appreciate any hints.

```
public static JSONObject requestWebService(String serviceUrl, JSONObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 600; 
    private static final int DATARETREIVAL_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 600
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL urlToRequest;
        String message;

        urlToRequest = new URL(serviceUrl);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(DATARETREIVAL_TIMEOUT);

        if (jsonObject != null) {
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            message = jsonObject.toString();

            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            os.write(message.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } else {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            throw new Exception("Acces unauthorized " + statusCode + ".");
        } else if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new Exception("Server unavailable " + statusCode + ".");
        }

    return new JSONObject(ReplicationClient.convertInputStreamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        fileLogger.error(logHeader + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new Exception("Error " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        fileLogger.error(logHeader + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new Exception("Error  " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fileLogger.error(logHeader + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new Exception("Error  " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        fileLogger.error(logHeader + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new Exception("Error  " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileLogger.error(logHeader + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new Exception("Error  " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the values for `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` and `DATARETREIVAL_TIMEOUT` ? are you aware that these methods takes the value in **milliseconds**? i think you have set the values as if they are **seconds** ?

Comment: Sorry, here they are: private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 600; 
private static final int DATARETREIVAL_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 600;

Comment: Just noticed that the OutputStream object was not closed, could that be the issue ?

Comment: values looks good to me, do you know after how much time the exception is thrown?

Comment: it just hangs there and then just throws the timeout exception (after 10 minutes, the time interval we set). @rhari, i tried closing the OutputStream object, but it did not make any difference..

Comment: may be the device you are using is consuming connection in some other apps that's why the response is delayed

Comment: after my theory has failed, now we start looking for strange answers :)... how about adding content-length header? like this `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF8").length);` put it just after `Content-Type` line

Answer (score 0):

<strike>after a second thought i have a theory
i will explain in details</strike>

but first try this code for *writing data*:

**remove this from your code:**

```
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
os.write(message.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

**use this:**

```
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write( message.getBytes());    
os.close();
```

if this works, then i will edit this answer and explain more.

This answer did not help as per the OP comment.
I am keeping this in case i found something else, otherwise, i will delete it later.

Comment: unfortunately no, it does not seem to make any difference.